# Linux Mint hardware support for MSI B360 MS-7B22

Tags: drivers, motherboard, linux-mint, gaming

On a whim, I tried dual booting Linux Mint 19.1 alongside my Windows installation on my gaming machine. After tweaking BIOS and grub settings (BIOS was set to fast-boot Windows and grub had Linux Mint as the default whereas I wanted Windows), I managed to get things booting the way I want, but the Mint installation does not recognize any of my hardware. I get the "using software emulation" message, and my Ethernet connection is not recognized (it's not listed under `ifconfig -a`, for example).

I know it's a driver problem, and searching for Linux drivers for the motherboard (MSI B360 MS-7B22) has turned up nothing. Does this mean I'm simply out of luck?

Comment: Your motherboard is new, some components may not have support yet but overall it has nothing special. An Ubuntu 18.04 based distro should support it. The "software emulation" sounds like graphics related, please [edit] and post the full hardware specifications and what tweaks in BIOS and grub settings. I hope you haven't installed Mint in legacy mode as the newer the hardware the more it needs UEFI mode or many hardware parts won't work correctly, Linux or Windows. And installing an OS or dual-boot is something that should be prepared, it shouldn't be done *on a whim*.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I updated my question a little, though I haven't posted full hardware specs yet. Can you explain what you mean by legacy mode? I just booted from USB, then ran the installer, telling it to repartition my secondary drive (not the same drive Windows is on).

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and again, for such new hardware you can't use any other than the native UEFI mode (you have UEFI, not BIOS, but UEFI also has a compatibility mode AKA CSM, Legacy or "BIOS mode"). How Mint was installed depends on how the installer was booted. Better to just disable CSM/Legacy to assure everything else happens in the correct mode.

Comment: My installation is using UEFI.

Comment: Ended up installing latest Ubuntu over the Mint install and it works great.